# Запуск Bash скрипта в определенное время

Tags: linux, bash

Есть bash скрипт для мониторинга сервиса, который нужно запускать 2 раза в день с 12.00 до 13.00 и с 19.00 до 21.00. 
Как установить дату запуска?
Crontab не подходит.
Спасибо

Comment: Добавьте подробностей в вопрос 1. Почему crontab неподходит? 2. Можно-ли скрипт запустить удаленно?

Comment: `while true; do if [[ $(date +%H) == 12 ]] || [[ $(date +%H) == 19 ]] || [[ $(date +%H) == 20 ]] || [[ $(date +%H) == 21 ]]; then набор команд; sleep 1m; else sleep 1m; fi; done` Ну как вариант бесконечный цикл, но это не правильно

Comment: У меня есть сервис, который нужно мониторить в определенное время. Если запустить в crontab то он будет чекать сервис и спамить

Comment: А если запустить любым другим способом - спамить не будет? Чем все-таки crontab не угодил, вы пробовали его? Вам нужно просто запустить скрипт два раза в день?

Comment: Скрипт мониторит сервис, и если там больше чем нужно значений то он будет присылать в телеграм сообщение. Если запустить через КРОН и чтобы он чекал сервис каждую минуту, то я буду получать спам в телеграм.

Comment: @rusdev1989, а при чем тут крон, он на функционал никак не влияет, что Вы просто с терминала запускаете что с крона

Answer (score 1):

- Прямые альтернативы к cron: anacron, fcron, Hcron, Jobber.
- Совсем другие технологии: systemd timers, jenkins, Amazon Web Services (AWS) Lambda, свои скрипты, например:

jobber.py на Питоне:

```
from subprocess import call
import time
while True:
    call(["php","cron.php"])
    time.sleep(120)
```

Comment: У меня на баше скрипт. Мне нужно в определенное время а не time.sleep(120) и без crontab

Comment: @rusdev1989, _man at_.

Comment: @rusdev1989, добавте проверку еще времени и после sleep проверяйте время, если оно подходит запускайте, если нет то просто пропускайте

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант запишите вашу конструкцию с while в скрипт. И запускайте его ежечасно через crontab.
Можно ежеминутно, но тут есть проблема в том, что скрипт выполнится 60 раз с 12 до 13 часов. Поэтому нужно создавать флаг-файл, который будет создан после первого выполнения задачи. А при последующих срабатываниях будет блокировать выполнение. Потом с 13 до 19 часов его нужно будет удалить.